# Add class to target based on radio input value (toggle, like function)

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, checked

## Summed up answer

**If you come across something similar here is the simple answer:**

In my code I get the .val() value of the :checked radio input, that gets the value of all the radios that have been checked, this results in unwanted classes. Taking advantage of the .click callback we can get the .val() value of just the specific input value of the clicked item, which is a radio label in my case.

Here is another great solution to the problem I had.. [Add class and remove class based on checked radio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368753/add-class-and-remove-class-based-on-checked-radio) and the jsbin to this solution http://jsbin.com/ugufi/27/

Hope this helps anyone else who may have the same issue... Pretty simple answer.. thanks to all!

## The Question

Here is the code I have

http://jsbin.com/ugufi/11/

What I am struggling with is finding a solution to removing the class after adding it to the target.

I have a list of radio buttons, I am getting the value of the :checked radio input and putting that value in a class.

When a new radio is checked It keeps adding onto the class ex

```
    <div class="radio1 radio2 radio3 radio4"></div>
```

What I need (which I know is very simple but Im not sure what to use).

```
   <div class="radio1"></div><!-- Radio input value with radio1 is checked -->
```

then when I check a new radio input

```
    <div class="radio4"></div><!-- Radio input value with radio4 is checked -->
```

PS. Ive looked this question up and found many answers but they all use some sort of .siblings() or .parent() callback, they are great solutions, but the inputs and the target are distant from eachother in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my answer to be more complete:

```
$('.moon-generator-attr').click(function() {
  var tabid = $(this).val();

  $('.icon-wrap a.icon').attr('class','icon icon-'+tabid);
  alert($('.icon-wrap a.icon').attr('class'));
});
```

This will make the class icon and whatever second class you'd like.  That way you can still access the element with `$('.icon-wrap .icon')`

You could also do this if you only have one "a" in your .icon-wrap div:

```
$('.moon-generator-attr').click(function() {
  var tabid = $(this).val();

  $('.icon-wrap a').attr('class','icon-'+tabid);
  alert($('.icon-wrap a').attr('class'));
});
```

Comment: ok .addclass and attr('class',) both still add the class to the target, but the question is how do I remove the old and add the new (based on checked state)

Comment: .attr("class", "value") is not adding a class, it's replacing the value of the class attribute.  So it will replace the old one with the new one.

Comment: well its because nothing is added initially i presume?

Comment: Yeah, thats crazy it works because instead of defining the :checked radio we just get the value of the radio that is clicked, so by taking advantage of the .click callback we dont even need to worry about the :checked value, just the clicked value

Comment: Well I wasted about 1 hour and 30 min just to find thats all it was.. WOW sucks to suck lol.. I knew it was something simple like that..

Comment: Applied it to the live code and works as expected! thanks... gonna give you +1

Answer (score 0):

Remove old class + add a new class

```
$(this).removeClass().addClass('icon-'+tabid+'');
```

Full code:

```
$('.moon-generator-attr').click(function() {
    var tabid = $('.moon-generator-attr:checked').val();

    $(this).removeClass().addClass('icon-'+tabid+''); 

      alert($('.icon-wrap a.icon').attr("class"));


});
```

Comment: im not removing the class from the label, this would equal the label class, correct me if im wrong?

Comment: the label class is .moon-generator-attr... my target to add/remove would be .icon-wrap a.icon