# Add class and remove class based on checked radio?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, addclass, removeclass

Here is my jsbin, http://jsbin.com/ugufi/11 I removed any attempt I made to remove the class, because it just kept alerting undefined.

My problem is when I add the checked class to my target I (as said above) fail to remove the class of the target.

I cannot use parent or sibling selectors, because the target is separate from my nested radio inputs.

When a new radio is checked It keeps adding onto the class ex

```
<div class="radio1 radio2 radio3 radio4"></div>
```

What I need (which I know is very simple but Im not sure what to use).

```
<div class="radio1"></div><!-- Radio input value with radio1 is checked -->
```

then when I check a new radio input

```
<div class="radio4"></div><!-- Radio input value with radio4 is checked -->
```

Comment: Is this different from your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367683/add-class-to-target-based-on-radio-input-value-toggle-like-function?

Comment: No, im assuming since you pointed that out this is frowned upon, but I am in desperate need of an answer, im pulling my hair out because I know its a simple little addition, but I cannot figure it out...

Comment: Also I thought if I reworded the title to be a little more simple I would get more answers

Comment: You should edit your original question if it's the same. Posting the same question multiple times in an effort to get a speedier answer is indeed frowned upon.

Comment: okay, if you are an admin or have the ability to remove this post go ahead.. I am just trying to move on with my project, I hate to skip steps, so I feel I cannot advance untill I get this little irritating piece of code out the way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not true, you can use `siblings` method, your element doesn't have to be a very next sibling of the selected element. By using `addClass` you should remove previously added classes, you can either remove those classes using `removeClass` method or overwrite the class attribute/property by setting a new value:

```
$('.moon-generator-attr').change(function() {
   var $this = $(this);  
   $this.siblings('.icon-wrap').find('a').attr('class', function(){
      return 'icon icon-' + $this.val();
   });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ugufi/22

Comment: Oh ok I didnt know siblings can extend that far, well I guess if you define the class then it would make perfect sense. This is a good answer, but actually there is a much simpler solution that I found to work for me, and that is to take advantage of the .click callback. Instead of defining the :checked value we just get the value of the clicked target value... http://jsbin.com/ugufi/25/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ugufi/27/ I updated your jsbin code with an alert incase anyone else views this, and yes its a great solution, thanks for taking time and helping.. Here is the code I went with http://jsbin.com/ugufi/25/ if it does happen to cause issues, or perhaps you see something wrong with this solution, ill definitely go with your piece of code. I cant thank you enough for helping!